# Atributos/Columnas duplicados tras consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Estoy empezando con SQL y estoy realizando una consulta en la base de datos del trabajo, he conseguido traer todo lo que quiero pero me trae columnas duplicadas, la consulta:

```
SELECT
    RAA.Id AS Original_Id,
    RAA.Id_Analisis,
    RAA.FechaRegistro,
    AAE.Descripcion,
    CAAEV.ValorCadena,
    CAAEV.Id_Concepto,
    CAAE.Nombre,
    CAAEV.ValorNumerico
FROM
    RegistroAnalisisActuacion RAA
INNER JOIN
    AnalisisActuacionExplotacion AAE ON RAA.Id_Analisis = AAE.Id
LEFT JOIN
    ConceptoAnalisisActuacionExplotacionValor CAAEV ON RAA.Id = CAAEV.Id_RegistroAnalisisActuacion  
LEFT JOIN
    ConceptoAnalisisActuacionExplotacion CAAE ON CAAEV.Id_Concepto = CAAE.Id  
LEFT JOIN
    AnalisisActuacionExplotacionLinea AAEL ON CAAEV.Id_Concepto = AAEL.Id_ConceptoAnalisis  
WHERE
    RAA.Id_Analisis = '56'
    AND CAAEV.Id_Concepto IN (664, 670, 672, 673, 674, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688);
```

Y las columnas que trae duplicadas (id1, version1.. etc)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿MySQL o SQL Server? Por otra parte, probablemente te falte un `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ¿De dónde salen las columnas? Porque no creo que salgan de la consulta que compartiste.

Comment: Así que no tienes ni `id` ni `version` en la cláusula `SELECT`, el resultado que estas mostrando no puede ser el resultado de la consulta que estas mostrando.